# How to configure Twilio sms gateway with rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twilio

I am trying to use the Twilio sms gateway in my application to send and receive sms. The used code is given below:

```
ACCOUNT_SID = 'accountsidgoeshere' 
ACCOUNT_TOKEN = 'token'
CALLER_ID = '(415) 599-2671'
req_params = {
            'From' => CALLER_ID,
            'To' => params[:number],         
            'Body' => 'This is message body'
        }
 account = Twilio::RestAccount.new(ACCOUNT_SID, ACCOUNT_TOKEN)
resp= account.request("/#{API_VERSION}/Accounts/#{ACCOUNT_SID}/SMS/Messages",'POST', req_params)
```

In response I am getting the following:

> You have attempted to use the Sandbox number to send a message to an unverified phone number.  Please verify the number to which you are attempting to send a message, or Upgrade your account and buy a number to use instead.

I am passing the number:mobile number which is already verified by the Twilio site.

Any hints and pointers will be a great help for me.

Comment: Email us help@twilio.com and we can help look at the specifics of what's going on.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like a configuration issue with your account or with the account ID you are passing in.  You should check w/ Twilio to get specific help and you should be able to check the logs there to get an idea of what's going wrong.

[Twilio Help](http://www.twilio.com/help)

Answer (score 2):

To use [SMS](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/sending-messages) and/or [call](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/making-calls) features from Twilio you need to have a [verified](https://www.twilio.com/help/faq/phone-numbers/whats-the-difference-between-a-verified-phone-number-and-a-twilio-phone-number) US number. (I guess, Twilio processes verification by calling the number.)

Another option is to buy a number from Twilio if you dont have a verified number from US.

Comment: Yes you are right, lastly while i was working with Twillio gateway then after i found this fact. And its difficult even test the application with the twillio sms gateway outside of US and Canada. Twillio can only send SMS within US/Canada.

Answer (score 0):

Are you passing the number formatted as E.164?